# MVC5 Retrieving Data from Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a controller with basic CRUD operations to handle my database and I wanted to add in a custom search function to search by name.

I tried to base my code off this because it's essentially the same and this one works fine.

```
// GET: Users/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

I'm trying to get a result to show up if I add a name to the url instead of the id.

```
// GET: Users/UserSearch/Smith
public ActionResult UserSearch(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    User user = db.Users.Find(name);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

When I try to use it I get:

[image: Error Image]

### Edit I have also tried this but to no avail:

```
public ActionResult UserSearch(string name)
{
    var user = from u in db.Users
               where u.UserName == name
               select u;

    return View(user);
}
```

And the error this throws:

[image]

Comment: the default routing looks for the parameter provided to be `id`, not `name`. change your method signature to be `string id` and the route will work. otherwise you need to set up a route for this action so it looks for the `name` parameter when loading from the url.

Comment: I didn't even think about the routing. I tried your suggestion but it broke the code.

At the line: `User user = db.Users.Find(id);`
I get an error stating: `Additional information: The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details.`

Comment: I'm more than happy to ditch the way I was trying I just don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to put the error details in the code, not an image of it. You hava method named `UserSearch` but you do not have a corresponding view named `UserSearch.cshtml` If you want to use the `Details` view, then use `return View("Details", user);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for **UserSearch** action method to work, you need to configure a route. For example,

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        /* You need this */
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Name",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
                UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

### Another Error - View is not found

**The view 'UserSearch' is not found** means you do not have UserSearch view. You need to create one.

Answer (score 0):

As a different way to try to create it, have you tried creating the model for it, then create a controller using that model?  You don't have to, but i know creating a model with the properties you want stored in the database is one way to have it do the work for you.

Just a thought, but the other problem is that does not tie into the user authentication (if that is what you are aiming for).

I would suggest creating a second instance of MVC to test out the model creation.  Just put properties in like `public string name { get;set; }` and anything else you want it to keep track of.

Edit: I think it would have been better to include the other steps.  I don't remember them as clearly from this point, but once you have a model created with the properties you want, you create a controller based off of that model.  This will create the controller and view that it needs to run.